# 2 nHibernate Mappings files, 1 POCO class.. SQL Profiler doing showing 2 queries running

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I currently have 2 hibernate mappings classes using the same POCO class, as the hibernate mappings relate to 2 very similar views and the same logic is being applied to these 2 views post retrieval, I thought it would work.

hdlquery = "from myFirstHibernateMapping"

The problem is that when I do a `hdlquery.List< MyPOCOClass>()`, it runs 2 queries, for both hibernate mappings class that use MyPOCOClass.  (I see this in SQL Profiler).

Anyone any idea why this is happening?  Or if there is a way around it?

Comment: I found a possible solution but not sure if it would work.. would someone know why polymorphism="explicit"  seems to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

define 2 different entitynames in the mappings and specify it in the query. Using criteria it would look like this

```
var results = session.CreateCriteria("MyPOCOClass1").List<MyPOCOClass>();
// and
var results = session.CreateCriteria("MyPOCOClass2").List<MyPOCOClass>();
```